# Move the star symbol into the top-right-corner of the union symbol

Tags: symbols, superscripts

I want to move the `*` into the top-right-corner of the union symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $${\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}}^* A_i$$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

I don't know how to move `*`. I try use silly way `\vspace` and it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $${\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}}^{\vspace{-0.2cm}*} A_i$$ 
\end{document}
```

So, how to move down the `*` symbol?

Comment: A fine-tuned solution: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[{\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}}
\setbox0\hbox{$\bigcup$}
\setbox1\hbox{$*$}
\mathclap{\hspace{-0.8\wd1}\raisebox{\ht0}{$*$}}{} A_i\]
\end{document}`

Comment: @anonymous - Or, just use the `\sideset` command of the `amsmath` package. See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569867/5001) for the details.

Comment: @Mico I fully agree that this is a much better solution. To be honest, I did not read the question carefully. I posted something that really   moves the * into the top-right-corner of the union symbol. (Please note that I am a guest, not a user, because I do not see myself accepting the terms of this site. As a consequence I cannot vote.)

Comment: @anonymous - Welcome to TeX.SE! Aside: I fully understand that people may have reservations and disagreements with the terms of the site.

Comment: @Mico Yes, being a enthusiastic LaTeX user and agreeing to commercial terms is something that I find hard to reconcile. I like LaTeX because it is *not* commercial. Nonetheless, I certainly do not doubt that you guys do a great service to the LaTeX user base.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `amsmath` package provides the `\sideset` macro for just your use case. Depending on your aesthetic preferences, you may wish to insert `\!` (negative thinspace) before the `A_i` term.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\sideset" macro
\begin{document}
\[
\sideset{}{^*}\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} A_i \qquad
\sideset{}{^*}\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} \! A_i
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: One may find more information about the `\sideset` macro in section 7.2 of the [user guide](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath) package. Just type `texdoc amsmath` at a command prompt to open the user guide in a pdf browser.